# Adapt elements to every screen size

Tags: html, css

I have three elements in top of my header: 1 select box, 1 input and 1 button. http://jsfiddle.net/cxnR8/37/

The problem is on this piece of code:

```
.header-search {
    max-width: 350px !important;
    width: 100%;
    /* IF INSTEAD OF 'WIDTH: 100%', I USE 'WIDTH: 350PX' IT WORKS ON LARGE SCREENS, 
     BUT IN SMALL ONES THE SELECT BOX KIND OF DISAPPEARS. */

    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

You can test an verify by yourself that if you change the width to a fixed one, the select box will disappear.

Comment: In my case, it does not disappear, but gets narrow (Chrome).

Comment: Yes..its kind of like that..how can I solve it?

Comment: How about displaying the select menu in a different row? Would you mind?

Comment: Actually yes..because this is on top of the header and I would like it to be in the center of the page in same line.

Comment: Btw, when I say smaller screens, I mean 1024x not mobile devices..

Comment: I got this: http://jsfiddle.net/cxnR8/86/

Comment: Made a few changes but worked. Thanks.